# RxJS Observables with large amounts of data

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Is there a performance hit (space/memory or time) when passing large amounts of data between an [Observer](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObserverDoc.html) and [Observable](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) in the browser?

For example, a browser application makes an asynchronous call returning a large amount of JSON.

Assuming multiple Observers are notified upon completion of said network call, should these Observers be provided with the JSON, or should they make a callback to an application-wide cache?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of one large network call, the major performance impact you'd see is the download time from the network, not in the JS. So no, having many subscribers to the Observable wouldn't be a problem.

If you are looking to reduce your subscribers, you may want to look into the **share() operator**: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md

If however you're making the same call many times, then of course you might want to rethink your design.